# Adding a back button to table view with embedded Navigation Controller Xcode

Tags: xcode

Here is the flow of my app so far.

View controller (HOME) with rect button (modal) linking to > Table view controller with an embedded navigation controller linked to> Multiple View controllers with an image on each.

This work perfectly s but......

I want to have a "back" button on my Table view controller to take me back to my (HOME) View controller.

I am new to this and have tried to find relevant info and tried loads of options but noting seems to work and although i can see a button in the simulator (and have Modal linked it to my (HOME) view ) the simulator crashes every time and this error message appears.....

***2013-01-05 17:19:40.080 MASTER DETAIL POLAR TEST[10975:f803] -[HomeController setCharacterNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894620
2013-01-05 17:19:40.084 MASTER DETAIL POLAR TEST[10975:f803]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeController setCharacterNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6894620'**

Please Help.....

Answer (score 0):

may it would be the best your HOME viewController is embedded in the navigationController an become RootViewController. By clicking the rect-button the tableViewController will appear.
Use the navigationControllers method – *pushViewController:animated:* or create a new segue an select "push".

If you don't like this way you have to add a navigationBarButtonItem to the navigationBar. Link this button item to an action which send the message *dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:* to the tableViewController. This should work.

Comment: Thank you! I figured this put not long before our reply but much appreciated !